# Qual a ordem de execução do Ionic?

Tags: ionic4

Sou iniciante no Ionic e estou meio perdido. Não sei exatamente onde e como adicionar componentes, e como tornar eles utilisáveis. Já me ocorreu de adicionar um componente e ele nem ao menos aparecer na tela. Talvez se eu entendesse como funcionam as estruturas eu pudesse adicioná-los sem problemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom se voce estiver falando de um componente criado por voce (fora do app.component), cada componente que voce cria tem um nome, no caso desse componente criado ele se chama app-example.  Dentro do componente que eu quero chamar ele (independe de qual for) eu preciso passar a tag com o nome dele

[image: nome da aplicacao example]

Lembre se sempre de verificar se voce tem ele declarado dentro do seu modulo o qual o componente faz parte (no meu caso no app.module)
NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ExampleComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: lembrando que a tag desse componente sera <app-example> </app-example>